# React native Firebase

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-firebase

I have peculiar issue, I have found many solutions for this error but none of them work.

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "RNFBApp":
In Podfile:
RNFBApp (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app`)

Specs satisfying the `RNFBApp (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

I have tried

```
 npm uninstall @react-native-firebase/app
 npm install @react-native-firebase/app
 cd ios/
 pod install
```

It didn't work.

I tried delete Podfile.lock and then running

```
 pod install --repo-update
```

Same error. I then tried changing the iOS deployment target to the highest 14.4 as well as my projects depoloyment target to 14.4.

It still failed. What is the cause? Any help please.

Answer (score 3):

`dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.`

in `ios/Podfile` you should have line like that -> `platform :ios, '9.0'`

change it to `platform :ios, '10.0'` or `platform :ios, '11.0'`

reinstall pods and rebuild project and check again